# Problems with mouse on Microsoft Virtual PC on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, virtualization, windows-server-2003

I am currently moving from windws XP to Windows 7.

I have a Windows 2003 VPC, that I previously ran using virtual PC on the Windows XP machine, without any problems.

I am using Hardware virtualization on the new machine.

The new machine is a Lenovo W500, the problem is the same using the internal mouse and my external Razor mouse.

The problem is that the mouse cursor appears to hang and then jumps across the screen.

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Surely this is a SuperUser question?

Comment: I considered putting it on SuperUser, but thought that more users here know about Microsoft Virtual PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you updated the Virtual Machine Additions software in the VM, or is it still running the older version from your previous machine?

Comment: Thanks, upgrading the integration features did the trick